# spring-cloud-stream application is looking for non-existent org.springframework.integration.endpoint.Pausable

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

A simple spring-boot application that I'm trying out based on one of the official examples is failing due to a weird error. Some class in spring-cloud-stream is looking for org.springframework.integration.**endpoint**.Pausable.

I see org.springframework.integration.**core**.Pausable (ie it's in a different package)
in spring-integration-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar.

The example is at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/processor-samples/streamlistener-basic

```
EDIT #1: I'm unable to find Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version of spring-cloud-stream-dependencies. I see the error below.

The only versions that I see are at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream-dependencies

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-dependencies:pom:Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
```

I have put the full stack trace, pom and three source files needed for recreating the issue.

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BindingServiceConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.example.scs.TypeConversionApplication.main(TypeConversionApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:569) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/endpoint/Pausable
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
 ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.endpoint.Pausable
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 ... 37 common frames omitted
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TypeConversionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TypeConversionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;

@EnableBinding(SampleSink.Sink.class)
public class SampleSink {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    // Sink application definition
    @StreamListener(Sink.SAMPLE)
    public void receive(ConsumerRecords consumerRecords) {
        logger.info("******************\nAt the Sink\n******************");
        // logger.info("Received transformed message " + foo.getValue() + " of type " + foo.getClass());
    }

    public interface Sink {
        String SAMPLE = "sample-sink";

        @Input(SAMPLE)
        SubscribableChannel sampleSink();
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

@EnableBinding(SampleSource.Source.class)
public class SampleSource {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.SAMPLE, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource() {
        return new MessageSource<String>() {
            public Message<String> receive() {
                logger.info("******************\nAt the Source\n******************");
                String value = "{\"value\":\"hi\"}";
                logger.info("Sending value: " + value);
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).build();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface Source {
        String SAMPLE = "sample-source";

        @Output(SAMPLE)
        MessageChannel sampleSource();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-3-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <kafka.client.version>2.3.1</kafka.client.version>
        <!-- spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Brooklyn.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring.cloud.stream.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring.cloud.stream.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.stream.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following in your POM

```
<kafka.client.version>2.3.1</kafka.client.version>
<!-- spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version -->
<spring-cloud.version>Brooklyn.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
<spring.cloud.stream.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring.cloud.stream.version>
```

So it's no longer the `official examples` since you're overriding dependencies and by doing so bringing potential incompatibility.

The whole purpose of having a BOM such as Hoxton means we ensure that user has compatible dependencies. Sure in certain cases certain overrides are possible, in your case I am not sure exactly what's going on since there is no spring-cloud `Brooklyn`. There is/was however spring-cloud-stream Brooklyn, but that is a very old version which is no longer supported or maintained (in fact for several years).

So, consider bringing your example back to it's original state at least form the standpoint of dependencies and then if you still have issues we can discus further.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry that I didn't mention the problem with using `Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` in the question. I see the maven download problems when I use that version . I will update the question with the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue but for different bean creation exception, upgraded to Hoxton.SR8 and it fixed my issue

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
       mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR8"
    }
}
```